# incompatible types object cannot be converted to Number

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to compile the below code but getting "incompatible types object cannot be converted to Number at `for(Number n:list)`.

```
import java.util.*;

 class Output
  {
    public static double sumOfList(List list)
    {
        double s=0.0;

        for(Number n:list)
            s+=n.doubleValue();

        return s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        List li=Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
        System.out.println(SumOfList(li));
    }
  }
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I really don't think this counts as a duplicate of that question. This question is simple enough there is probably some duplicate out there, but the one above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chage your code to this:

```
public static double sumOfList(List<Number> list){
..
}
```

Comment: thanks i changed in my code so now it work

Answer (score 4):

Listen to the "Raw types" warning your compiler outputs and [**use generics.**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Declare the list type as `List<Number>` or `List<? extends Number>`.

http://ideone.com/L6mIhA

(and [*never* use raw types.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) They only exist for backwards compatibility.)